# What does 'Unexpected token: punc ({)' mean while running my gulp task for managing css?

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

This works superbly for the scripts task.
But when I run my gulp task to output my css I get this error:

```
`Unexpected token: punc ({)`
```

The task seems to work in 'development' but not in production.

[This is the whole gulpfile.js](https://gist.github.com/antonioOrtiz/2abb5edc57142adb98b2)

These are my variables which I set.

```
var env,
jsSources,
sassSources,
outputDir;

jsSources = ['components/js/**/*.js'];
sassSources = ['components/scss/**/*.scss'];


 env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

 if (env === 'development'){
    outputDir = 'builds/development/';
    sassStyle = 'expanded';
 } else {
    outputDir = 'builds/production/';
    sassStyle = 'compressed';
 }
```

And this is css task:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
return gulp.src(sassSources) // we use addsrc to add our .js files to the mix
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(addsrc(mainBowerFiles())) 
    .pipe(filter('*.css'))
    .pipe(order([
        'normalize.css',
        '*'
    ]))
    .pipe(concat('main.css'))
    .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', uglify()))
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    })
    .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(notify({
            message: "Sass tasks have been completed!"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + 'css'))
});
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a CSS syntax error?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. I do get an output file (actual .css file) when running in `development` and I tried running that file through a linter and I didn't get a bracket error.

Comment: Ok then. Shouldn't you end the `return` statement with a semicolon? (on lines 47 and 69 of your gulpfile)

Comment: Ahh, I thought that would do it! But no! Thanks though!

Comment: This -> **".. to add our .js files to the mix"**. Why on earth would you do that? :D. Are you by any chance trying to minify css with [gulp-uglify](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify) there?

Comment: Oh sorry that's the note I had originally in the comments for the 'js' version...

Comment: Hey Heikki, your observation did the trick!! Turned out I left the `gulp-uglify` in the css task! THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

So in summary [Heikki comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510087/what-does-unexpected-token-punc-mean-while-running-my-gulp-task-for-manag#comment41659224_26510087). Don't use `uglify` on CSS files, use `uglifycss`.